# How angular load module & controller in different file by routing

Tags: angularjs

i am very new in angular and learning angular v1+. just come across a example which show how to load controller by routing when all controllers in same file.

code taken from https://scotch.io/tutorials/single-page-apps-with-angularjs-routing-and-templating

### see the code details

```
// script.js

    // create the module and name it scotchApp
        // also include ngRoute for all our routing needs
    var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute']);

    // configure our routes
    scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider

            // route for the home page
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })

            // route for the about page
            .when('/about', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
                controller  : 'aboutController'
            })

            // route for the contact page
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
                controller  : 'contactController'
            });
    });

    // create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
    scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {
        // create a message to display in our view
        $scope.message = 'Everyone come and see how good I look!';
    });

    scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
    });

    scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
    });
```

### html

```
<!-- index.html -->
<body ng-controller="mainController">

    <!-- MAIN CONTENT AND INJECTED VIEWS -->
    <div id="main">
    {{ message }}

    <!-- angular templating -->
    <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>

</body>

<!-- home.html -->
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h1>Home Page</h1>

<p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>

<!-- about.html -->
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h1>About Page</h1>

<p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>

<!-- contact.html -->
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
<h1>Contact Page</h1>

<p>{{ message }}</p>
</div>
```

now my question is if about and contact controller reside in different module in different folder then how angular routing would load these modules when user click on links?

so please tell me how to instruct angular routing to load controllers in different module with path ?

please discuss with a small example. thanks